# Split self-intersecting path into simple non-self-intersecting paths

Tags: algorithm, geometry

What is an efficient way to split a self-intersecting open path into multiple simple non-self-intersecting paths?

Path is in 2D space made of connected line segments. It can be represented by a collection of points, where the first point is a start of a path and the last point is an end of a path. (e.g. black path in the picture)

I'm using Clipper2 library to create a buffer around a path (blue outline in the picture is the desired outcome), but `Clipper.InflatePaths()` doesn't support self-intersecting paths. So, I need to break down any complex (self-intersecting) path into multiple simple (non-self-intersecting) paths (see right side of the picture for example), as an intermediate step of buffer creation.

1. Split complex path to simple paths
2. Create buffer around each simple path (`Clipper.InflatePaths()`)
3. Union all buffers (`Clipper.Union()`) to create a single buffer polygon.

[image]

Comment: Depends on your definition of "path".

Comment: @n.m. Path in 2D space made of connected line segments. It can be represented by a collection of points, where the first point is a start of a path and the last point is an end of a path.

Comment: Are you talking in the context of graph theory, or of (computational) geometry?

Comment: Then each segment is a simple non-self-intersecting path. You may want to find paths that do not intersect each other though. In this case run an intersection finding algorithm such as sweeping line.

Comment: @Berthur In the context of geometry. I'm using Clipper2 library to create a buffer around a path, but it doesn't support self-intersecting paths. So, I need to break down any complex path into multiple simple paths.

Comment: It would help if you post an image of some path and of the resulting buffer you want to get.

Comment: @n.m. I've added an example image. Desired buffer is shown in blue around the left path. Paths on the right are expected simple paths that I would like to create from an example self-intersecting path on the left (as an intermediate step of buffer creation).

Comment: Would be nice to incorporate comments into the question, as they focus it in a way otherwise unobvious.

Comment: It is unclear how splitting the path will actually help with creation of the buffer. Even if you split 0-1-2-3 into 0-X-3 and1-X-2, X is still an intersection point and the two buffers created separately for these two paths will intersect in the vicinity of X. To obtain the picture of the buffer you show, you will have to merge separate buffers. But if you do that, you don't need to find any self-intersections, just create a buffer around each segment, and merge those.

Comment: @n.m. Actual paths will have many segments. I'm afraid that creating buffer for each line segment and merging them will be too inefficient.

Comment: You can find all intersections, it is not that complicated, and then find long paths/cycles in the resulting graph.

Answer (score 1):

There are certainly ways to do what you ask for, but there are easier ways to do what you *want*.

The easiest way is to inflate each line segment separately and then union all the results.

The next-easiest way is to break paths to keep the range of directions travelled along the path within 180 degrees, since it is impossible for resulting path to intersect itself.

Comment: Isn't the 1st method kind of inefficient with long paths? Second method sounds interesting. So, copy edges to new path while sum of angles is below 180° and when sum of angles would go above 180°, start a new path and repeat until all the edges are copied?

Comment: Inefficient?  Maybe a little. It's super easy to try it and see.  For second method you keep track of the "total turn", and when max_turn - min_turn would go above 180 degrees, you break the path.

Comment: Unioning individual buffers could produce artifacts of varying ugliness at the joints, depending on how the buffering algo does ends and turns. If the ends and turns are rounded, then unioning is going to be expensive. In either case it could be desirable to keep the number of unions to a minimum.

Comment: @n.m. maybe -- it depends on how the library does the end/corner rounding.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Are min/max turns min/max of total_turn? `if (abs(max_total_turn - min_total_turn) > 180)` ?

Comment: @zigzag yes.  The first segment has current_turn=0.  Every other segment has an angle relative to the original direction.  You can keep track of that by adding up all the turns you encounter along the way, with say left turns negative and right turns positive.  Remember the max and min and then do the calculation as you say.

Comment: @MattTimmermans so min and max is actually left_turns_sum and right_turns_sum? I feel like I don't fully understand the concept.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Just to clarify, one 90° left turn and one 90° right turn count as 180° total turns (which means path will split)?

Comment: when you turn left, you go from 0 to -90.  When you turn right again, you go from -90 to 0.  min is -90 and max is 0 -- don't need to split the path.  The idea is that if there is a vector such that (the projection of) every path segment moves in a positive direction along that vector, then the path cannot self-intersect.  There is a vector like that if all the path segment directions fit into 180 degrees.

Comment: @zigzag Note: It looks like the Clipper2 library will work fine with self-intersecting paths.  It warns against self-intersecting polygons, but that's not what you have.  Internally, that program is going to work by making shapes for all the path segments and connections, and doing a union.

Comment: @MattTimmermans I tried inflating each path separately and the result is correct. But if I perform an union operation on these polygons one of them gets skewed. Distortion is highest at the intersection. I just tried NTS's `CascadedPolygonUnion` to perform the union and it creates the same skewed result. I'm thinking it might be a precision issue, as offset amount for inflation is relatively very small. In my test the points are coordinates in a Mercator projection and offset for inflation is 500 meters. Which results in a very narrow outline.